# How can connect from one computer to another computer using python

Tags: python-3.x, wmi

I wanted to connect from one computer to another computer using python, (or remote computer)
I have installed wmi module and trying to use below code for connection from one computer to another computer,

```
ip = '100.00.00.00'
username = 'MyuserName'
password = 'myPassword'
#import sys, wmi
from socket import *

try:
    print("Trying to connect %s" %ip)
    wmi.WMI(ip, user=username,password = password)
    print('connected')
except wmi.x_wmi:
    print("Wrong username or password"
```

While running above code, I am getting error - *except wmi.x_wmi:
NameError: name 'wmi' is not defined*

Could you please help me for connecting from one computer to another computer

Thanks in advance 
RaviK

Comment: You may need to `import wmi` before trying to use it....

Comment: try uncommenting line 4, `#import sys, wmi` to begin with

Comment: I have tried both the options, but getting same error.  import wmi  & import sys, wmi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your fourth line:

```
#import sys, wmi
```

probably just needs to be uncommented

```
import sys, wmi
```

If you still get the error you might need to install the wmi library